# Method to convert infix to Reverse Polish Notation(Postfix)

Tags: algorithm, search, postfix-notation, infix-notation, shunting-yard

Is there any method beside Dijkstra shunting yard algorithm to convert infix to RPN ? I'm trying to study about shunting yard algorithm's weakness and advantages by comparing it to another conversion method. Any links to shunting yard algorithm's journal is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: 1. Recursive descent. 2. LALR(1). 3. Table-driven LL(1). 4. Floyd precedence parser (obsolete). ...

Answer (score 2):

In real life, I always parse expressions recursively.

In python, the basic algorithm looks like this:

```
import re
import sys

def toRpn(infixStr):
    # divide string into tokens, and reverse so I can get them in order with pop()
    tokens = re.split(r' *([\+\-\*\^/]) *', infixStr)
    tokens = [t for t in reversed(tokens) if t!='']
    precs = {'+':0 , '-':0, '/':1, '*':1, '^':2}

    #convert infix expression tokens to RPN, processing only
    #operators above a given precedence
    def toRpn2(tokens, minprec):
        rpn = tokens.pop()
        while len(tokens)>0:
            prec = precs[tokens[-1]]
            if prec<minprec:
                break
            op=tokens.pop()

            # get the argument on the operator's right
            # this will go to the end, or stop at an operator
            # with precedence <= prec
            arg2 = toRpn2(tokens,prec+1)
            rpn += " " + arg2 + " " +op
        return rpn

    return toRpn2(tokens,0)

print toRpn("5+3*4^2+1")

#prints: 5 3 4 2 ^ * + 1 +
```

This form is easily adapted to handle parentheses, unary operators, and operators that associate right-to-left like the assignment operator.

Note that the above code doesn't handle syntax errors appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is, LR parsing, parser combinators, probably many other [kinds of parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Parsing_algorithms).